# How do I create several different sheets in excel using jxl.jar and a while loop?

Tags: java, jxl

I am trying to write code that will create multiple sheets based on the amount of array objects I have stored. Currently is breaks at `WritableSheet excelSheet = Work.getSheeet(sheetCounter)`. Giving me an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. It will run once but on the second run breaks.

```
public class DailyFile {
int i = 0; 
static int sheetCounter = 0;

private WritableCellFormat arialBold;
private WritableCellFormat arial;
private String inputFile;

public void setOutputFile(String inputFile) {
    this.inputFile = inputFile;
}

public void write() throws IOException, WriteException {
    File file = new File(inputFile);
    WorkbookSettings wbSettings = new WorkbookSettings();

    wbSettings.setLocale(new Locale("en", "EN"));

    WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(file, wbSettings);
    workbook.createSheet(finalGui.ExperimentCodeList.get(sheetCounter).toString(), sheetCounter);
    WritableSheet excelSheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetCounter);
    createLabel(excelSheet);
    // createContent(excelSheet);

    workbook.write();
    workbook.close();
}
```

This is where it calls the function to write.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws WriteException, IOException {
    DailyFile test = new DailyFile();
    test.setOutputFile("c:/Users/sbutler/Desktop/CERES_Daily-BLIND_TEST.xls");
    while (sheetCounter <= finalGui.ExperimentCodeList.size()){
        System.out.println("I RAN!");
        test.write();
        sheetCounter++;
        System.out.println(sheetCounter);
    }
    System.out.println("Please check the result file under c:/Users/sbutler/Desktop/CERES_Daily-BLIND_TEST.xls ");
}
```

Here is the stacktrace

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 30, Size: 1
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
at jxl.write.biff.WritableWorkbookImpl.getSheet(WritableWorkbookImpl.java:408)
at gui.DailyFile.write(DailyFile.java:47)
at gui.DailyFile.main(DailyFile.java:293)
at gui.finalGui$4.mouseClicked(finalGui.java:127)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Please post a code response as I am struggling with this problem for some time.

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Reason.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 30, Size: 1
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
at jxl.write.biff.WritableWorkbookImpl.getSheet(WritableWorkbookImpl.java:408)
```

The first 4 lines of the stack trace says you're trying to access a value to the Index 30 in a size 1 array. It also says where: at the line `WritableSheet excelSheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetCounter);` of your `write()` function.

The 2 lines before this are:

```
WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(file, wbSettings);
workbook.createSheet(finalGui.ExperimentCodeList.get(sheetCounter).toString(), sheetCounter);
```

It says: create a new workbook and a new sheet inside, for each call of `write()`. Hence, `createSheet(String name, int index)` documentation says:

> Creates, and returns a worksheet at the specified position with the specified name If the index specified is less than or equal to zero, the new sheet is created at the beginning of the workbook. If the index is greater than the number of sheet, then the sheet is created at the end of the workbook.

The end here will always be at index 0, since the Workbook is always brand new. On the next instruction, when you try to access a sheet of index 30, it raises an exception because the only one you can get is at index 0.

### How to fix it?

Here is the logic (I'll let you write the code).

1. Create pour xls file, create an empty workbook. (Initialization phase)
2. Loop on your workbook to create sheets, the way you did. (What you really want to do)
3. Close everything you need to close - at least the workbook. (Leave everything clean and tidy)

### A bit of code

The main changes are:

- Use of the constructor
- Loop moved into `write()`
- New `write()` parameter (for the loop)
- Use the returned value of `workbook.createSheet`

I can't compile it, but it should look like this.

```
public class DailyFile {
    int i = 0;

    private WritableCellFormat arialBold;
    private WritableCellFormat arial;
    private String inputFile;

    public DailyFile(String inputFile) {
        this.inputFile = inputFile;
    }

    public void write(int sheetCount) throws IOException, WriteException {
        // Step 1: Initialization
        File file = new File(inputFile);

        WorkbookSettings wbSettings = new WorkbookSettings();
        wbSettings.setLocale(new Locale("en", "EN"));

        WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(file, wbSettings);

        // Step 2: Main logic
        for (int index = 0; index < sheetCount; index++) {
            WritableSheet excelSheet = workbook.createSheet(finalGui.ExperimentCodeList.get(index).toString(), index);
            createLabel(excelSheet);
            // createContent(excelSheet);
        }

        // Step 3: Closing
        workbook.write(); // <-- maybe in the loop?
        workbook.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws WriteException, IOException {
        DailyFile test = new DailyFile("c:/Users/sbutler/Desktop/CERES_Daily-BLIND_TEST.xls");
        System.out.println("I RAN!");
        test.write(finalGui.ExperimentCodeList.size());
        System.out.println(sheetCounter);
        System.out.println("Please check the result file under c:/Users/sbutler/Desktop/CERES_Daily-BLIND_TEST.xls ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the input! I am still not clear on how to fix the issue though as I thought I was already doing your steps (obliviously I am wrong in this thinking) 

I am not sure why it is looking for Index 30 on the second call as this should be looking for Index 1 on the second call then 2,3,4,....as the Write() function is looped over in the main function.

What you are saying make sense to me and is how I thought I was approaching this but I am clearly wrong.

Could I bother you for some code to help me along??
Either way thank you for the input!

Comment: The reason why it stops at the second call is because you had a `static sheetCounter` that you do not reinitialize to 0. I removed it in the code refactoring I proposed, find a workaround if you used it somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks very much, I have been struggling with this for sometime. Thank you again!

Comment: No need for thanks. Just validate the answer if this is what you needed so anyone else coming here will know where to look.

Comment: Much better! Now but seems to have error when the sheet is being named the same thing as the previous sheet. Excel recovers the sheet and all the data is written to the sheet but for some reason it has a problem with having the same name on different sheets.

Comment: Yeah I guess you just can't have two sheets with the same name. It would make sense to me that excel puts this restriction.